# File on sd card displayed in android emulator's gallery app

Tags: android, gallery, emulation, sd-card

I have created an app which lets the user save an image to the sd card, but I cannot see it in the gallery app on my emulator. I'm not sure if I need special code for this or what but I need to be able to find it so that I can see if my code actually works.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to be able to find it so that I can see if my code actually works.

If your ultimate objective is to see the files on the SD card, then that can be achieved in several ways:

- Use file explorer that comes bundled in Android Debug Monitor.***
- Login to device/emulator shell, `adb shell`, and navigate to SD card folder (that's usually at `/sdcard` or `/mnt/sdcard`) and use `ls` command to list the contents.
- Install/use one of many available file explorer apps and navigate to SD card through the device/emulator UI.

***Example:

- Launch the ADM by running `monitor` command (if the SDK tools is not in your path, then first navigate to  tools/ directory).
- There will be several perspectives: LogCat, Threads, Heap, etc. You need to switch to File Explorer tab.

[image: Android Debug Monitor]

- Above is File Explorer view for Galaxy Nexus, the actual path for SD card may differ for your device/emulator.

Comment: If all you want to do is confirm that the file is being created this is correct.  However if you really do want the image to be added to the gallery on the device MediaConnectionScanner is what you'll need

Comment: This should work perfectly, but I'm a complete noob to this stuff so I don't know how to do any of these things

Comment: @James, added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok I just looked all over eclipse for this window but I don't see it in any of the tabs(file, edit, etc.). Could you better explain how to find it please?

Comment: This is not Eclipse, it is Android Debug Monitor. Please read the first line of the example carefully.

Comment: Ok, so where do I open this from then? Is it in the emulator? Or is it special to physical devices?

Comment: It's under the `tools/` folder in Android SDK

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the File to the media Library look at the [MediaScannerConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html).  You will need to call the ScanFile (after connected) and then the image will be added to the gallery.

Comment: Would you mind posting some code on how to do this? I realized that I need to see it in gallery and don't know how to use MediaScannerConnection?

Comment: If I want to be able to view my file in the gallery using the MediaScannerConnection, how do I do this?